# How do i count for a specific data in a column in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, count, model, foreign-keys

I have two models, One is Employees and other one is Skill. One Employee can have many skills. Now I'm trying to show number of employees that possesses each consecutive skill in skills view page.

My Skills View Page:

```
 <tbody>

                    @foreach ($skills as $skill)
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{ $loop->index+1 }}</th>
                            <td>{{ $skill->skill_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $skill->totalEmp($skill->id) }}</td>
                            <td style="width: 25%;">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" title="Delete Skill">Delete Skill</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach

                </tbody>
```

Skills Model:

```
class Skill extends Model
{



  use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'skill_name'
];

public function Employee()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Employees::class, 'skill_id', 'id');
}


public function totalEmp($id){
    return Employees::where('status', 1)->where('skill_id','=',$id)->count();
}


}
```

Employees Model:

```
class Employees extends Model
```

{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $guarded = [];

protected $table = 'employees';

public function Skills(){
    return $this->hasMany(Skill::class);
}
}
```

Employee table has->skill_id, other irreverent fields || Skill Model has->id and skill_name field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withCount` method for this.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

On your `Skill` model you have `Employee` relationship defined.

So you will be able to do something like this:

```php
$skills = Skill::withCount(['Employee'])->get();

// Prints out number of employees that posses first skill
echo $skills[0]->employee_count;
```

Of course you can iterate through `$skills` with `for` loop, or `foreach` and similar, or even use collection methods.

```html
<tbody>
   @foreach ($skills as $skill)
   <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ $loop->index+1 }}</th>
      <td>{{ $skill->skill_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $skill->employee_count }}</td>
      <td style="width: 25%;">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" title="Delete Skill">Delete Skill</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

If you still want to use your method `totalEmp` you can modify it like this:

```php
public function totalEmp(){
    return $this->employee()->count();
}
```

One other thing that I strongly recommend is to make sure you name your models and relationships properly.

Models should be named like: `Skill` and `Employee`
Relationships should be named like: `employees()` and `skills()`

Please see example here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many